# Template repeat not working for nested list (Polymer.dart)

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Due to the lack of multi-dimensional array support in dart, I thought of using List.

**Dart code :**

```
class MyModel extends Object with Observable {
@observable
List<List<int>> dataList = toObservable(new List<List<int>>());
}

void main() {
  initPolymer().run(() {
    Polymer.onReady.then((_) {
      var template = querySelector("#bindValueTemplate") as AutoBindingElement;
      var model = template.model = new MyModel();

      for (int i=0; i<2;i++) {
        List<int> in1 = new List<int>();
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
          in1.add(j);
        }
        model.dataList.add(in1);
      }

    });
  });
}
```

**HTML file (snippet):**

```
<body fullbleed touch-action="auto">
 <template id="bindValueTemplate" is="auto-binding-dart">
    <div id="dynamic_area" layout horizontal>
       <table template repeat="{{row in dataList}}">
           <tr template repeat="{{col in row}}">
              <td>{{col}}</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
 </template>

</body>
```

**Error I get in console:**

```
Uncaught Error: Error evaluating expression 'row': Class 'MyModel' has no instance getter 'row'.
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'row'
Receiver: Instance of 'MyModel'
Arguments: []
```

When I added a 'row' list variable in MyModel with a getter, it throws the following error :

**Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: can't eval an 'in' expression**

Comment: It could be https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12742. Can you please try if it works inside a Polymer element instead of AutoBindingElement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of template repeat was wrong. The repeat clause is to be applied for the the element itself, and not the children. This fixed the problem :

```
<body fullbleed touch-action="auto">
 <template id="bindValueTemplate" is="auto-binding-dart">
    <div id="dynamic_area" layout horizontal>
       <table>
           <tr template repeat="{{row in dataList}}">
              <td template repeat="{{col in row}}">{{col}}</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
 </template>

</body>
```

And the updated dart code :

```
class MyModel extends Object with Observable {
@observable
List<List<int>> dataList = toObservable(new List<List<int>>());
@observable
List<int> row = [];      //I don't know why it works even without toObservable()
}
```

I am marking the question as resolved because my specific problem was resolved. But the question still remains what if we actually want to repeat table elements !

Comment: I think I am only allowed to accept my own answer after 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

You assign the model to the template and only afterwards add the data.

I guess you need to make the inner lists observable too.

```dart
List<int> in1 = toObservable(new List<int>());
```

or a bit shorter

```dart
List<int> in1 = toObservable(<int>[]));
```

But the error message seems to point more to this issue http://dartbug.com/12742

Can you please try if it works inside a Polymer element instead of AutoBindingElement.

#### EDIT

Normally you don't add `repeat` on an element. Normally you use

```dart
<template repeat="{{x in y}}">
  <!-- repeate this y.length times -->
</template>
```

There are exceptions. For example `<ul>`, `<tr>`, and a few others,
because browsers do not allow HTML like

```dart
<table>
  <!-- this template element is just dropped by some browsers because 
       only some specific elements are allowed inside a `<table>` element. -->
  <template repeat="{{x in y}}">
    <tr>
    </tr>
  <!-- repeate this y.length times -->
</template>
```

As a workaround for such situations

```dart
<table>
  <tr repeat="{{x in y}}"> <!-- here not the children but the element itself is repeated -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not 12742, that wasn't even a bug as there were two separate binding delegates. That would be analogous to two nested auto-binding-dart elements: the nested element does not see the scope of the outer element.

Comment: Thanks Gunter. In the past I have failed to achieve data binding (even one-way) without AutoBindingElement. Will let you know. As of now, I have added a solution to my problem, but there are open questions in that solutions you may help with your comments. Thanks again !!

Comment: I updated my answer. Inside a Polymer element you don't need the AutoBindingElement. If your HTML is not inside an Polymer element you can use AutoBindingElement to make binding work. Without both binding is not supported.

Comment: Hi Gunter, As you requested, I am trying similar usecase with PolymerElement, but it's not working : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613136/databinding-on-user-action-not-working-in-polymer-dart