# Polymer does not work on IE 11 with template repeat generating an HTML table

Tags: html, polymer

This HTML using Polymer works in Chrome, IE 11 and Firefox:

```
<polymer-element name="greeting-tag">
  <template>
      <template repeat="{{s in salutations}}">
        {{s.what}},{{s.who}}
      </template>             
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('greeting-tag', {
      ready: function() {
        this.salutations = [
          {what: 'Hello', who: 'World'},
          {what: 'GoodBye', who: 'DOM APIs'},
          {what: 'Hello', who: 'Declarative'},
          {what: 'GoodBye', who: 'Imperative'}
        ];
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

but when the template repeat is replaced with code rendering an HTML table:

```
<polymer-element name="greeting-tag">
  <template>
    <table>
      <template repeat="{{s in salutations}}">
        <tr>
            <td>{{s.what}}</td>
            <td>{{s.who}}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>             
    </table>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('greeting-tag', {
      ready: function() {
        this.salutations = [
          {what: 'Hello', who: 'World'},
          {what: 'GoodBye', who: 'DOM APIs'},
          {what: 'Hello', who: 'Declarative'},
          {what: 'GoodBye', who: 'Imperative'}
        ];
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

it works in Chrome and Firefox, but it **does not work in IE 11** (the element is not rendered at all). Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this problem has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25576262/2345933), this works:

```
<polymer-element name="greeting-tag">
  <template>        
   <table>
     <tr template repeat="{{s in salutations}}">
       <td>{{s.what}}</td>
       <td>{{s.who}}</td>
     </tr>
   </table>     
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('greeting-tag', {
      ready: function() {
        this.salutations = [
          {what: 'Hello', who: 'World'},
          {what: 'GoodBye', who: 'DOM APIs'},
          {what: 'Hello', who: 'Declarative'},
          {what: 'GoodBye', who: 'Imperative'}
        ];
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```